# What can I do if my T4i becomes unresponsive while in live-view?

Tags: troubleshooting, live-view, canon-650d

Recently I got a Canon Rebel T4i camera. Yesterday, when I was happily trying out different features, I got it locked such that no button was responsive anymore, that include the on/off button. I wasn't able to switch any modes, turn it off to reset it, nothing. But the camera was still on without letting me do anything with it. The only thing I could think of doing was to remove the battery for a bit and than things got back to normal. However, I don't find this behaviour to be normal, yet is something that it could be just poor operation on my part , although I doubt that. What I figured got the camera in this lock state is trying to switch the shooting mode, from the main scene selector dial while previewing the scene in live mode. Maybe the position of the mirror while changing the shooting mode would have something to do with it.
So, I wonder if anyone has experienced the same thing, is this a malfunction or is it a common occurrence for a DSLR. I'm not sure that this is what cause it but the camera becomes unresponsive, yet the power is remaining on apparently when changing the shooting mode (let's say M to Av or Av to Tv) while having the live view on.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound normal. I'd advise you to update to the latest firmware, but there are none that have been provided for the T4i/650D yet. So your best shot would be to bring it to the Canon Service center and get it looked at. Or even better, get it exchanged in the shop if it's still possible.
If you manage to reproduce the issue consistently, it also would be good to report the problem to canon directly so that they can confirm if it's a firmware issue and work on a fix.